# Merge similar strings together in pandas column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have pandas crosstab dataframe which looks like this:[image]

This is a small sample of the whole dataframe. As you can see, sku1_entity has some strings like 4 Cheese W Verm, 4 Cheese w Verm, 4Cheese w Verm and similarly there are more such cases in the whole dataframe. Correspondingly we have 0.0 and 1.0 values against each row. I want to merge these similar strings(maybe based on similarity score) and club the corresponding 0.0 and 1.0 values.

So the output for 0.0 and 1.0 would be like (for 4 Cheese W Verm):

0.0 = 6 +55 + 3 = 64
1.0 = 6 + 60 + 4 = 70

As I'm a beginner, Please help me out how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a universal solution but it should give you an idea how you could tackle it: use some function to 'normalize' your `sku1_entity` column and group on these normalized values like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'sku1_entity': ['4 Cheese W Verm','4 Cheese w Verm','4Cheese w Verm', 'something else'], '0.0': [6,55,3,1], '1.0': [0,5,1,0]})
df = df.set_index('sku1_entity')
df['All'] = df['0.0'] + df['1.0']
def grouper(x):
    return ''.join(x.lower().split())
df.groupby(grouper).sum()
```

Result:

```
               0.0  1.0  All
4cheesewverm    64    6   70
somethingelse    1    0    1
```

As an alternative you could of course 'normalize' the column before creating the pivot table in the first place.

---

If you want to retain the original `sku1_entity` names, you could do something like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'sku1_entity': ['4 Cheese W Verm','4 Cheese w Verm','4Cheese w Verm', 'something else'], '0.0': [6,55,3,1], '1.0': [0,5,1,0]})
df['sku1_entity_norm'] = df['sku1_entity'].str.lower().str.split().map(''.join)

df.groupby('sku1_entity_norm').agg({'sku1_entity': list, '0.0': sum, '1.0': sum})
```

Result:

```
                                                         sku1_entity  0.0  1.0
sku1_entity_norm                                                              
4cheesewverm      [4 Cheese W Verm, 4 Cheese w Verm, 4Cheese w Verm]   64    6
somethingelse                                       [something else]    1    0
```